# jwt: Why is signature algorithm not needed when verifying a JWT token?

Tags: authentication, jwt, jjwt

I'm reading the overview of the [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) library:

Building the token is done as following:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.MacProvider;
import java.security.Key;

// We need a signing key, so we'll create one just for this example. Usually
// the key would be read from your application configuration instead.
Key key = MacProvider.generateKey();

String compactJws = Jwts.builder()
  .setSubject("Joe")
  .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, key)
  .compact();
```

And the token is verified as:

```
try {

    Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(compactJws);

    //OK, we can trust this JWT

} catch (SignatureException e) {

    //don't trust the JWT!
}
```

`SignatureAlgorithm.HS512` is not used on the second snippet. How is it inferred? Or is it not necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because JWT includes the algorithm in the header, so the validator knows which algorithm need to use simply decoding the first part of the token

For example, if you decode the first part of this token (test at https://jwt.io/)

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.O8YgYdD1YxficWfO_06nDsm_YgDdXmgMM4CN3bLor5c
```

corresponds to

```
{
  "alg": "HS512",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

Comment: But don't you need the algorithm to decode that first part?

Comment: No. The header (first part) and payload ( second part) are base64url encoded. The signature algorithm is only necessary to verify the signature (third part)

Comment: ok I guess I should take a close look at the RFC docs. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As @pedrofb mentions the algorithm is conveniently included in the header, and in case of an asymmetric algorithm you can also find the key that was used via the `kid` header parameter.

Heads up that you should be very careful to **only allow the algorithms that you *expect* when decoding**. Otherwise you might accept a token that was signed with `alg=none`, essentially bypassing any verification.

Most decoders have support for this (and if they don't, they should). Your particular example though seems worrisome as

```
//OK, we can trust this JWT
```

might not be true if your parser also accepts `alg=none`. So take care!